# Unable to create a Collection Type Dependency Property

Tags: c#, list, dependency-properties

I'm trying to create a custom list which features a List of objects. Though when this is set both in the Xaml and the code behind I get a "Incorrect markup error". Below is how I'm settings up the PropertyKey and Property.

```
private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ItemSourcePropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
        "ItemSource",
        typeof(List<object>),
        typeof(MultiSelectComboBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty = ItemSourcePropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
```

The Field is:

```
 public List<object> ItemSource
    {
        get { return (List<object>)this.GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
    }
```

The error I get is:

```
{"Cannot create instance of 'Window1' defined in assembly 'GroupExpansion, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error in markup file 'Window1.xaml' Line 1 Position 9."}
```

Has anyone bound a DependencyProperty to a List before? I've come across a few tutorials but when I try to emulate the tutorials it falls on it's face. The List and Property are in a file which extends a UserControl. If you need any more details just ask. I've been banging my head off the keyboard now for a couple of days. Seem to be going round in circles.

Cheers

Comment: Is there an inner exception to the one you mention above?

Comment: Yep a very helpful: {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}, the source was: "PresentationFramework". Oh I noticed that I left out the constructor for the Property which is done in the class constructor and assigns a empty List<object> to it

Comment: Ah ha, a bit more information. I changed the List to an ObservableCollection and upon doing that, it then produced the following error in the InnerException: 'ItemSource' property was registered as read-only and cannot be modified without an authorization key. Now to search for a way around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, It would seem that the Dependency Property needs to be attached to a ObservableCollection. And then for binding it then need to be non read only so the DependencyPropertyKey can be dropped and replaced with only the DependencyProperty. Would be incredibly useful if someone set up an actual page for this.